# coldfusion error message

Tags: coldfusion

I'm getting the following coldfusion error message

```
Could not initialize class coldfusion.tagext.NativeCfx
```

I've tried searching google but can't find anything on thsi error. has anybody come accross this before?

Thanks

James

Comment: During what conditions are you seeing this?

Comment: Are you seeing a coldfusion.tagext.LibMissingException in the stack trace?

Comment: There should be some additional info as a part of the error that might be more useful. But given the info on hand I'd say you are are trying to access a CFX Tag that is not registered in the CF Admin or it may have something to do with an incorrectly installed instance of FusionReactor (a popular CF monitoring application that runs as a servlet and collects and displays data from CF and the JVM).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you've got a CFX tag that is no longer playing nice.  It could be that it is no longer registered in the ColdFusion administrator or the dll is corrupt.

A stack trace will always include lines in the code where the error is occurring. Take a look and see if you can spot a line of code that uses a CFX prefixed tag call. Once you know what the tag is, check the CF administrator to make sure that the CFX tag is present there and take a look to make sure that the physical file it relates to can be found on the server as well.